# Shift and Split

Tags: perl, split, shift

i want to make this 2-Commands shorter, 1 line if it possible.

```
my $id = shift;
my @splittedID = split(" ", $id);
return $splittedID[0];
```

but it should have at the end the same functional. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return (split " ", shift)[0];
```

Or, if you want:

```
(split " ", shift)[0];
```

(The result of the last line of a sub implicitly becomes the return value).

Even shorter (Perl 5.16 required for `/r` option):

```
$_[0]=~s/ .*//r
```

Of course, in actual production code, your original example is better, since it's readable.

Comment: how gonna he know what he should split or shift if you dont defeind $id in the Command ?

Comment: @user3075044, $id was just a temporary variable created during the task and not necessary.

Comment: i like your answer, but the thing is, First i shift the content of $id and then i split it .. so if i write in the subrotine just return (split " ", shift)[0]; it woudn't be enough right ?

Comment: @user3075044, no.  You are shifting from the default array.  Either `@_` if this is in a subroutine, or `@ARGV` if not.

Answer (score 1):

Because you just want the first item of the `split` and `' '` is a special pattern that skips all leading spaces, a regex can also solve this like so:

```
sub firstword {
    return (shift =~ /(\S+)/)[0];
}

my $x = firstword('asdf qwer jkl') # Equals 'asdf';
my $y = firstword('     qwer jkl') # Equals 'qwer';
my $z = firstword('             ') # Equals undef;
```

Also, the `return` keyword is optional of course, but shorter is not always better.

Comment: Yes, that is technically true for a general zero width split pattern, but `' '` is a special case.  It skips all preceding spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more compact using a regular expression:

```
sub first_field {
  return unless $_[0] =~ /(\S+)/;
  $1;
}
```

Comment: I expected the following code to fail: `sub ff {$_[0] =~ /(\S+)/;$1;} "test" =~ /(\w+)/; $x = ff('asdf qwer'); $z = ff('         ');`.  However, I forgot that capture variables are localized to their block, so `$z` equals `'test'` and not `'asdf'`.